# Is it possible to data-bind visible to the negation ("!") of a boolean ViewModel property?

Tags: knockout.js

I'd like to use a property on my ViewModel to toggle which icon to display without creating a separate computed property of the inverse. Is this possible?

```html
<tbody data-bind="foreach: periods">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <i class="icon-search" data-bind="visible: !charted, click: $parent.pie_it"></i>
      <i class="icon-remove" data-bind="visible: charted, click: $parent.pie_it"></i>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

My ViewModel has a property periods which is an array of month, like this:

```
var month = function() {
    this.charted = ko.observable(false);
};
```

Comment: @Niko: It's not really a duplicate question. The OP of the question you refer to already knew **that** it's possible to data-bind the negation of an observable, but wonders why it needs to be called like a function. This question's OP here didn't know how to do that in the first place and obviously didn't find that other question. I'm glad I found this question here - which is mostly thanks to its descriptive title.

Answer (score 287, accepted):

When using an observable in an expression you need to access it as a function like:

`visible: !charted()`

Comment: Maybe we should make a hidden binding :) We have enable and disable.

Comment: Does the documentation disagree with this, or am I completely misunderstanding this page: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html

Comment: Nevermind, I guess "isSevere" is not an observable but a plain old property, thus my confusion.

Comment: When using !charted, you're getting ![Function]. [Function] is truthy, ![Function] becomes false and will always be false if you use that syntax. http://jsfiddle.net/datashaman/E58u2/3/

Comment: They actually added `hidden` binding in [v3.5.0](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html)

Answer (score 53):

I agree with John Papa's comment that there should be a built-in `hidden` binding. There are two benefits to a dedicated `hidden` binding:

1. Simpler syntax, ie. `hidden: charted` instead of `visible: !charted()`.
2. Less resources, since Knockout can observe the observable `charted` directly, rather than creating a `computed` to observe `!charted()`.

It's simple enough to create a `hidden` binding, though, like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.hidden = {
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.visible.update(element, function() {
      return !ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    });
  }
};
```

You can use it just like the built-in `visible` binding:

```
<i class="icon-search" data-bind="hidden: charted, click: $parent.pie_it"></i>
<i class="icon-remove" data-bind="visible: charted, click: $parent.pie_it"></i>
```

Comment: this did not work for me without return `return !ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());`

Comment: Thanks @MehmetAtaş - I corrected the `hidden` binding per your comment. (BTW, I was using CoffeeScript in my project at the time I posted this originally. CoffeeScript's syntax doesn't make it obvious when a return is intentional.)

Answer (score 10):

It's little confusing, as you have to do

```
visible:!showMe()
```

so, i did

```
<span data-bind="visible:showMe">Show</span>
<span data-bind="visible:!showMe()">Hide</span>
<label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:showMe"/>toggle</label>​
```

my model is

```
var myModel={
    showMe:ko.observable(true)
}
ko.applyBindings(myModel);
```

​
check in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/khanSharp/bgdbm/

Answer (score 4):

You could use my [switch/case](https://github.com/mbest/knockout-switch-case) binding, which includes `case.visible` and `casenot.visible`.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: periods">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="switch: true">
        <i class="icon-search" data-bind="case.visible: $else, click: $parent.pie_it"></i>
        <i class="icon-remove" data-bind="case.visible: charted, click: $parent.pie_it"></i>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

You could also have it as

```
        <i class="icon-search" data-bind="casenot.visible: charted, click: $parent.pie_it"></i>
        <i class="icon-remove" data-bind="case.visible: $else, click: $parent.pie_it"></i>
```

Comment: I just realized that this is an old question but hope this could be useful to someone.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make the binding aware of changes to the property, I copied the visible binding handler and inverted it:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.hidden = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var isCurrentlyHidden = !(element.style.display == "");
        if (value && !isCurrentlyHidden)
            element.style.display = "none";
        else if ((!value) && isCurrentlyHidden)
            element.style.display = "";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: this solution is for entertainment purposes only.

```
ko.extenders.not = function (target) {
    target.not = ko.computed(function () {
        return !target();
    });
};

self.foo = ko.observable(true).extend({ not: null });

<div data-bind="text: foo"></div>     <!-- true -->
<div data-bind="text: foo.not"></div> <!-- false -->

<!-- unfortunately I can't think of a way to be able to use:
    text: foo...not
-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue about how to use an opposite of a boolean observable. I have found an easy solution:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
var self = this;

// When program start, this is set to FALSE
self.isSearchContentValid = ko.observable(false);


self.gatherPlacesData = function () {

   // When user click a button, the value become TRUE
   self.isSearchContentValid(true);

};
```

Now on your HTML you should do this

```
<p data-bind = "visible:isSearchContentValid() === false"> Text 1</p>
<p data-bind = "visible:isSearchContentValid"> Text 2</p>
```

When the program starts only "Text1" is visible because "false===false is TRUE" and Text2 is not visible.

Lets say we have a button which invokes the gatherPlacesData on click event. Now Text1 won't be visible because "true === false is FALSE" and Text 2 only be visible.

Another possible solution could be using computed observable but, I think is a overcomplicated solution for a so simple problem.

Answer (score -1):

Also can use **hidden** like this:

```
 <div data-bind="hidden: isString">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: settingValue" />
                        </div>
```